# How can do sorting in MongoDB in respect to another collections data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have three collections.

items

```
{
_id
}
```

user

```
{
_id
}
```

item_user_info

```
{
_id
item_id (FK item)
user_id (FK user)
}
```

I need to sort the documents from the item collection by priority, where priority is:
- If the combination of item_id & passed user_id exist in item_user_info then priority=1 else 0.

Question: What will be the query?

I can also modify the schema if you suggest and if it will fast the query.

Note: Users and items will increase timely in millions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field called `priority`, populate it in a callback setting it to 1 or 0 based on the rules you described. When retrieving data, sort by this field. You may also consider adding an index on it.

That said, your chosen schema is not well suited for MongoDB. You will likely be able to query your data more efficiently by rethinking how you manage associations.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.
Could you please suggest batter schema for these three collections.

Comment: That is not a simple question to answer, and one which is impossible to answer without knowing a good amount of information about your application and in general what it is trying to achieve.

You can start by reading this post: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1